# Permissions in android 6.x

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-viewpager, runtime-permissions

I have an app, there is a `viewPager`, where I'm adding my photos from gallery.

In older versions that was working cool, but starting from android 6.0 and higher I need to ask permissions at runtime. I've done that. But the problem is that when I'm allowing the permissions, image is not loading in `viewPager` and after second time the image loads good.

**viewPager adapter** (I'm loading my images from gallery)

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private ImageView imageView;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public ArrayList<String> listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<>();
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;

public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestRead();
        checkPermission();
    } else {
        getAllShownImagesPath();
    }
}

private void requestRead() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    } else {
        getAllShownImagesPath();
    }
}

private void checkPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        getAllShownImagesPath();
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listOfAllImages.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photopager, null);
    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photoView2);

    Glide.with(context).load(listOfAllImages.get(position))
            .thumbnail(1f)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imageView);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) container;
    viewPager.addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    View view = (View) object;
    vp.removeView(view);
}

private void getAllShownImagesPath() {
    Uri uri;
    Cursor cursor;
    int column_index_data;
    String absolutePathOfImage;
    uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};

    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
            null, null);

    column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
        listOfAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImage);
    }

    cursor.close();
}
}
```

How to load images after clicking *allow* in permission request?

This is adapter because I can't override `onRequestPermissionsResult`.

Comment: have you checked my answer on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807882/android-request-run-time-permission-not-working/50807900#50807900)?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let's try to see the source of the problem you are having:

it is not working the first time because you are executing something asynchronously and expecting to get the results synchronously:

```
requestRead();
checkPermission();
```

so, when you call checkPermission(); the permission has not been granted yet.

The possible solution is:

Handle the permission request in your activity or fragment: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989288/onrequestpermissionsresult-not-being-called-in-fragment-if-defined-in-both-fragm?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions/38563687#38563687), and this is the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=en-419) which you should be familiar as you has implemented this feature before. Then, when the permission is granted

```
onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
```

you can let the adapter know (adapter.readPermissionGranted() just as an example) so that it can fetch the images (getAllShownImagesPath();).

Comment: So I don't need to do anything in adapter? Only in activity?

Comment: if that pagerAdapter is inside a fragment I recommend you to check for permission inside the Fragment, otherwise do it inside the Activity. Then, as I wrote in my answer, let the adapter know that it has permission for reading.

Comment: Actually you can move all the logic of fetching the path of images in the Activity or fragment and pass the list of String as a parameter to the PagerAdapter., but that  is up to you and has nothing to do with permissions :)

Comment: I have fragment. I done the permission check inside the fragment and I want to let the adapter know I need to call adapter.getAllShownImagesPath();  ?

Comment: you can do it after you are sure you have permission through "onRequestPermissionsResult" or when you check for permission .

Comment: I tried to call adapter.getAllShownImagesPath() in onRequestPermissionsResult after checking permission granted or not but that not works)

Comment: can you paste the code where you create the adapter and where you are call getAllShownImagesPath()?

Comment: Ok, but let's continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173068/discussion-between-name-surname-and-leandro-ocampo).